# node.js/ File.on close socket?

Tags: node.js, file, sockets

I use node.js, and I open a socket. I have the next code:

```
 var file = fs.createReadStream(file1);
     file.on("data", function (data) {
            socket.write("blabla");
     });
     file.on("close", function (close){
}
```

It gives me the next error:

```
{ [Error: This socket has been ended by the other party] code: 'EPIPE' }
```

If I put `socket.write("blabla");` before file.on, It works well.

How can I write to my socket?

Comment: It means the socket has been closed from the other side. The server to which the socket connects closes its end before you can write.

Comment: @user568109: But why outside the file.on it works well?

Comment: When outside it can be executed when file has not been read, the socket is open then. But it may take time to read file fully. So before it can fully read (end event) the socket can be closed.